# Second lookup based off the first lookup output

Tags: ssis

Using a data flow task in SSIS,for a specific Id I need to fetch a description from two tables.First table should be join on ParentTable.Id to get ParentTabel.Description and second join should be with SubCatagoryTable.ParentId column to get SubCatagoryTable.Description. Then I have to keep then non NULL value, except if both description is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

use one query.

```
select coalesce(sub.ID,cat.ID) as ID,coalesce(sub.Descr,cat.Descr) as Descr
from CategoryTable cat
left join SubCatagoryTable sub on cat.ID=sub.ParentID
```

Update based on your comment:

Use two lookups (set no match as ignore which will leave nulls for no match:

First Lookup:

Set UsingSubDescr equal a match on:

```
select sub.ID,cat.Descr as Descr
from CategoryTable cat
    join SubCatagoryTable sub on cat.ID=sub.ParentID
```

2nd Lookup:

Set UsingParent on match on:

```
Select ID,descr
from ParentTable
```

Now use derive Descr:
Descr = isnull(UsingSubDescr) ? UsingParent : UsingSubDescr

Comment: at sub category table at row level I have got the provider Id, so I don't have the category description.

Comment: @Proffesore -- Update based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

Do a single lookup against a query that does an OUTER JOIN from your category table to your sub-category table and COALESCE the description column, so that if the description from the sub-category table is NULL (ergo not in the table) then use the description from the category table.

Comment: what I gain with an outer join on the same table?

Comment: typo.   I meant join the category to the sub-category.   I will correct.

Comment: He's going run into trouble when an ID is in both data sets (because they are keys in different tables). That's why I changed to a double lookup and then derive.

Comment: An alternative could be a lookup to select distinct ID, description of the union of the two lookup queries. Could I use your answer with a modification or it would work only if the provider name was existing in both cat and subcat tables?

Comment: From what's posted in the question and the other answer, it's not clear to me why this answer won't work as is.  Maybe if you posted your table definitions and sample data, I could help further.